# HTML containing SVG to HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css, xml, svg

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to "convert" SVG into HTML + CSS, knowing that I only have text tags on this SVG.

Here's a snippet of a file I have:

```
<text class="c3 c2 c10 c11" id="p2">
    <tspan id="l3" x="85.018 88.172 90.5185 93.4635 97.6245 100.5695 104.40749 107.3525 112.074 116.938 120.7 123.0465 127.768 132.632 136.394 139.339 143.13899 148.03149 152.6485 155.717 159.479 162.424 167.25949 171.0215 173.96649 181.44299 185.28099 189.51801 191.9595 196.681 201.545 205.30699 208.252 212.09 215.035 219.082 223.69901 226.1405 229.29449 232.2395 236.4765 238.823 241.2645 244.33301 247.4015 251.1635 254.3175 257.26251 262.1265 267.11398 270.87601 273.82101 278.63751 282.47549 286.71249 290.47452 293.41949 299.63251 303.3945 308.1445 311.08951 314.15802 318.77499 323.63901 326.70749 329.6525 331.88501 334.11749 336.55899 344.03549 348.85202 353.716 356.0625 359.13101 361.57251 366.18951 371.177 374.12201 378.95749 383.8215 386.76651 391.60199 396.21899 398.66049 402.89749 405.81403" y="118.809">
    This is a text
    </tspan>
</text>
<text class="c3 c2 c10 c11" id="p3">
    <tspan id="l4" x="85.018 91.63 96.24699 103.7235 111.2 114.962 117.394 120.0825 122.315 124.7565 127.103 129.535 133.696 136.12801 139.966 144.013 147.851 150.2925 153.209 155.64099 157.9875 161.8255 164.25751 169.12149 174.10899 176.541 184.0175 188.63451 193.62199 198.4575 202.2195 204.6515 207.56801 211.40599 216.39351 220.63051 223.07201 227.82201 230.1685 233.9305 236.3055 238.73749 242.5755 245.33051 250.28949 254.05148 258.9155 262.06952 265.9075 270.89499 273.81152 276.2435 280.08151 282.51349 284.85999 288.698 291.13 294.19852 299.0625 302.29251 305.04749 308.8855 312.68549 316.44751 318.87952 323.715 327.47699 329.909 332.14151 334.37402 338.13602 341.936 345.09 348.92801 353.9155 356.2905 358.7225 364.2135 369.20099 371.633 375.737 379.49902 382.65298 385.09448 388.01102 391.77301 394.14801 396.58002 401.4155 405.17749" y="132.308">
    Another text here
    </tspan>
</text>
```

Also, sometimes I have images with the `image` tag containing a `xlink:href` attribute.

I don't know much about SVG, but I know this is a XML-based vector image format.

Comment: Why would you convert it? You can embed SVG in html and it would display as is.

Comment: To convert it into epub afterwards.

Comment: You are using a particular ability of the svg text and tspan elements which is the positioning of every glyphs through a set of x values. In my knowledge, there is no such thing in HTML + CSS, so you would have to split each glyph into span elements, and set their positioning through CSS.